# Лишний ноль справа у NUMERIC

Tags: php, postgresql, double

При внесении в базу данных значения 0.00001 (или меньше) справа есть лишний ноль.
Тип данных этого поля в базе Postgresql - NUMERIC.

Руками, через терминал, INSERT в базу - нет лишнего ноля справа.
PHP, используя pg_query_params() - есть лишний ноль справа.

```
<?php

#условная "копейка" (0.01) дробится ещё на миллион (0.00 000 001)

define('KNBBET1', 0.00000100); //сто
define('KNBBET2', 0.00001000); //тысяча
define('KNBBET3', 0.00010000); //десять тысяч

echo gettype(KNBBET1).' '.KNBBET1."\n<br>\n"; //double 1.0E-6 (лишний ноль справа)
echo gettype(KNBBET2).' '.KNBBET2."\n<br>\n"; //double 1.0E-5 (лишний ноль справа)
echo gettype(KNBBET3).' '.KNBBET3."\n<br>\n"; //double 0.0001 (нет лишнего ноля)

?>
```

Comment: А чем с точки зрения математики отличаются `0.000001` и `0.00000100` ?
Если же Вам нужно именно выводить с разной точностью после запятой, несмотря на то с какой большой точностью число хранится в БД - используйте функции PHP `sprintf` или `number_format`.

Comment: 0.000001 и 0.00000100 отличаются избыточными данными в базе. С выводом на вебстраницы проблем нет.

Comment: измените размерность поля `numeric(1,6)` например, ну или сколько Вам нужно знаков `до` и `после` запятой

Answer (score 0):

Встретился с подобной проблемой в t-SQL (Transact-SQL/MSSQL) и нашёл решение.

При составлении результирующей таблицы в столбцах, которые имели изначально заданный тип NUMERIC(24, 3) добавлялись значения с уточнением до 4-го знака после запятой (пример: выводило 20.0000, а ожидалось 20.000).

При этом простой тест с SELECT'ом выдавал корректное значение

```
SELECT CAST(1 as NUMERIC(24, 3))  >>  1.000
```

Было опробовано решение завернуть в cast с тем же NUMERIC(24, 3) столбцы в SELECT'е результирующего набора, но это не дало результата, также выдавало с уточнением до 4-го знака.

### Решение

Удалось получить корректные значения, заменив **NUMERIC(24, 3)** на **DECIMAL(24, 3)** при создании таблицы для результирующего набора:

```
SELECT CAST(1 as DECIMAL(24, 3))  >>  1.000
```